# unable to find version npm react

Tags: reactjs, npm

below is the error,

```
unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! Found: react-dnd@9.5.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dnd
npm ERR!   react-dnd@"^9.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-dnd@">= 2.0.0 < 3.0.0" from reactabular-dnd@8.16.0
```

below are the pacakges am using,

```
  "reactabular-dnd": "^8.16.0",
  "react-dnd": "^9.4.0",
```

Can anyone help me with this? it says reactabular-dnd@8.16.0 requires react-dnd version less than 3 but i require latest react-dnd too

Comment: reactabular needs react-dnd version to be 2 or 3. In order to fix this.. downgrade react-dnd or install legacy-peer-deps

Comment: tried both with legacy peer deps npm install succesfull but getting into another issue if i run npm run build

Comment: yes, it would go into unexpected issues because the latest versions are not supported by reactabular

Answer (score 1):

`reactabular-dnd` which is pretty outdated (last publish 4 years ago) requires a `react-dnd` version below `< 3.0.0`. Yours is at `9.4.0` way above what's required.

Downgrading `react-dnd` would work, but this is not what you want. Installing with `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` should ignore the error and possibly `reactabular-dnd` will just work fine with a newer version of `react-dnd`. You can also try [overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides).

Comment: If I do this npm install is successful but am getting  'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' if I run npm build after that install

Comment: The reason for that may be that the versions are incompatible.